# How to redirect 'http://my-domain.com:8080' to 'https://ci.my-domain.com'?

Tags: jenkins, redirect, apache2

I already set the domain `https://ci.my-domain.com/` up correctly, this already works with jenkins. Now I am trying to get rid of the default `http://my-domain.com:8080` URL by trying to redirect it to `https://ci.my-domain.com/`.

Is there a way to achieve this?

I already tried:

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
  ServerName my-domain.com
  ServerAlias www.my-domain.com

  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://ci.my-domain.com/$1 [NC,R,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to "get rid of" the default port 8080, you can just stop jenkins from accepting remote connections. That way jenkins is only available through the reverse proxy to localhost:8080. See [How can I get Jenkins to stop listening for remote connections?](https://serverfault.com/questions/233951/)

Comment: No I only want jenkins to be accessible through https://ci.my-domain.com

Comment: @Devxln that's what i mean, you want to disable the *remote* port 8080, then reverse proxy the *local* 8080 to ci.your-domain.com